# HTML: selecting radio-button by clicking on cell - code working in Chrome, not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, radio-button

This is my JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function handleRadioRow() {
        var t = event.target;
        if (t.tagName == "input")
            return;
        while (t.tagName != "th")
            t = t.parentElement;
        var r = t.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
        r.click();
    }
</script>
```

And this is my HTML:

```
    <form action="order.php">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th onclick="handleRadioRow()"><input type="radio" name="date" value="08-14">August 14<br><?php echo($price) ?></th>
                <th onclick="handleRadioRow()"><input type="radio" name="date" value="08-15">August 15<br><?php echo($price) ?></th>
                <th onclick="handleRadioRow()"><input type="radio" name="date" value="08-16">August 16<br><?php echo($price) ?></th>
                <th onclick="handleRadioRow()"><input type="radio" name="date" value="08-17">August 17<br><?php echo($price) ?></th>
                <th onclick="handleRadioRow()" bgcolor="#00FF00"><input type="radio" name="date" value="08-18" checked="checked">August 18<br><?php echo($price) ?></th>
                <th onclick="handleRadioRow()"><input type="radio" name="date" value="08-19">August 19<br><?php echo($price) ?></th>
                <th onclick="handleRadioRow()"><input type="radio" name="date" value="08-20">August 20<br><?php echo($price) ?></th>
                <th onclick="handleRadioRow()"><input type="radio" name="date" value="08-21">August 21<br><?php echo($price) ?></th>
                <th onclick="handleRadioRow()"><input type="radio" name="date" value="08-22">August 22<br><?php echo($price) ?></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

This is not working at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vitaly_zdanevich/qcnc456r/) at Chrome too.

Or maybe you know another method to get radio-button selected when push/click on cell?

Comment: link of your jsfiddle

Comment: Why is this tagged `jquery` if you’re not using any?

Comment: Sorry, yes this is JavaScript, not jQuery, I fixed question and added link to jsfiddle.

Comment: I noticed that call to your function handleRadioRow() fails. It never goes in the function. So could not get what is expected. If you have attach working fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple and without JavaScript! Just warp `input` with `<label>`

Before:

```
<th onclick="handleRadioRow()"><input type="radio" name="date" value="08-14">August 14<br></th>
```

After:

```
<th><label><input type="radio" name="date" value="08-14">August 14<br></label></th>
```

But with little minus - user can click only in text, not on empty spaces - it is much better than only to radio-button.
http://jsfiddle.net/vitaly_zdanevich/qcbqtxh9/

Answer (score 0):

...or you could do as wished for in the first place. ;-)
Add a "this" to the javascript call for all table cells:

```
<th onclick="handleRadioRow(this)">
```

Then update your js-function to the following (given that you are using jQuery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function handleRadioRow(el) {
    var radioBtn = $(el).find('input').first();
    radioBtn.prop('checked',true);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
function handleRadioRow(obj) {
    $(obj).find('input:radio[name=date]').prop('checked',true); 
    }
```

Here is a jSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kggys40k/

I don't know why this function when kept in javascript block doesn't work in fiddle. So i have kept it inside html block itself inside using script tag and tested.

P.S: Use *this* keyword while invoking handleRadioRow() function.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use jquery etc...

```
function handleRadioRow(event) {
    var t = event.target;
    if (t && t.tagName == "INPUT")
        return;
    while (t && t.tagName != "TH") {
        t = t.parentElement;
    }
    var r = t.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0];
    r.click();
}
```

and use it as

```
<th onclick="handleRadioRow(event)"><input type="radio" name="date" value="08-14">August 14<br><?php echo($price) ?></th>
```